# Jaxb2Marshaller not rejecting date in format YY-MM-DD

Tags: spring, xsd, jaxb2, spring-restcontroller

I am having a restful service and an input date element. The date element is defined as below :

```
<xs:simpleType name="DateOfBirth">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:date"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

where xs is xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

My requirement is that date in format YYYY-MM-DD should be accepted and any other format is invalid date. Now when I put date in YY-MM-DD (e.g 16-01-01) then  the Jaxb2Marshaller  is marshalling it as correct date whereas it should be rejected as wrong format.

Can you help me with what changes I need to do in schema so as to accept only YYYY-MM-DD as valid dates.

Comment: I am not sure why the schema was not printed in the question. Giving it again:   <xs:simpleType name="DateOfBirth">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:date"/>
 </xs:simpleType>

Comment: Hi,Can anybody help me on this please.                                                          Thanks,                                                                                                            Satish